# How to write the following code in efficient way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am applying filters based on the selection of radio button, how to make it more efficient without using if condition

```
 applyExtraFilter() {
        this.moreFilter = !this.moreFilter;
        this.allItems = this.listings;
        if (this.deliveryConcession[0].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.deliveryConcession[0].checked);
        }
        if (this.deliveryConcession[1].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.deliveryConcession[2].checked);
        }
        if (this.deliveryConcession[2].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.deliveryConcession[3].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[0].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.seatConcession[0].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[1].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.seatConcession[1].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[2].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == this.seatConcession[3].checked);
        }
        this.setPage(1);
    }
```

Comment: any specific reason you're explicitly accessing `this.deliveryConcession` items instead of iterating over it?

Comment: no specific reason actually

Comment: I had a solution for you but I've realized that you are iterating in the first case over only `[0, 2, 3]` and in the second case `[0, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Try to filter just one time at the end, there you can apply all the filters. you can use a structure like `let filters = { delivery1: true, deliver2: false, delivery3: true, seat1: true ...}` to hold the values of the current ifs.

Comment: Is that lazy copy and pasting or are the filters not meant to match the if statement?  If the filters are meant to match then this is very simple

Comment: @camaron i dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` function.

**Note**: It would be easier if you would iterate over all elements of the `this.deliveryConcession` and `this.seatConcession` variables. In your case, I had to add extra conditions in every loop concerning the index.

```js
applyExtraFilter() {
  this.moreFilter = !this.moreFilter;
  this.allItems = this.listings;

  this.deliveryConcession.forEach((v, i) => v.checked && (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 3) ? this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == v.checked) : v);

  this.seatConcession.forEach((v, i) => v.checked && (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 3) ? this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking == v.checked) : v);

  this.setPage(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter only once, you can do more improvements for sure.

```
applyExtraFilter() {
    this.moreFilter = !this.moreFilter;
    this.allItems = this.listings;
    this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => {
        let result = true;
        if (this.deliveryConcession[0].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.deliveryConcession[0].checked) {
          result = false;
        } 
        if (this.deliveryConcession[1].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.deliveryConcession[2].checked) { 
          result = false;
        }
        if (this.deliveryConcession[2].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.deliveryConcession[3].checked) { 
          result = false;
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[0].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.seatConcession[0].checked) { 
          result = false;
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[1].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.seatConcession[1].checked) { 
          result = false;
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[2].checked && fil.seatingConcession.parking != this.seatConcession[3].checked) { 
          result = false;
        }

       return result;
    });
    this.setPage(1);
  }
```

I have used `let` to declare `result`, if that keyword gives you issues with your IDE use `var` instead.